# Change language forever

Tags: google-maps, localization

Trying to change the default language in Google Maps by settings in Menu > Language. But it sets required language just for current settings. Next time I open Google Maps I have the previous language. How to set new language forever?

Answer (score 1):

- open this link **https://myaccount.google.com/language**
- change your language as desired
- if its set on desired language and doesn't display desired language at all, just set it on any different language and then set it back